# Div width inside an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, text, width

I have an iframe and with it a body and a div

```
 <iframe name="myiframe">
    <html><head></head>
    <body>
    <div style="width: 100%;">This is my test text</div>
    </body>
    </html>
 </iframe>
```

The iframe has specific width. Let's say 100px. And the div get the 100% of it. The problem is that the text I have in the div is not all visible. I can see only what fits to 100px and the rest is hidden, while I want it to split into two lines in case is not fit.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It works fine for me. The elements have some styling you're not showing us. Does the embedded page's body have a fixed width?

Comment: In the HTML you posted the </head> tag is in the wrong place. It should come before the <body> tag. iframe usage here: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: yes ok the head ect was just an example. The body no has not a fixed width, has nothing as width.

Comment: Please create a fiddle showing your full html/css.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the body should not be in the head (as seen in your example).

Next, I believe the text within the iframe is what is viewed when the iframe is not supported by the browser. To properly use an iframe, you must save your html into a separate file and use the src attribute to load the file into the frame.

Something like this should work:

page1.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <iframe src="page2.html">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="width: 100%;">This is my test text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information, check out W3Schools:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: I am using Firefox which supports iframe. And unfortunately the page2.html is not an option for me. I have to do it the way I show you in my code.

Comment: You can't do it the way you show in your code. If the browser does support iframes, it shows nothing. I'm surprised you even see any content in the iframe.

Comment: ok thanks I will check, maybe is something else wrong in the code in general then.

Comment: The purpose of an iFrame is to load another HTML page into the current page without redirecting. If you are just embedding HTML statically into your page, then just use a div.